Raster option in QGIS 3.36
I have rasterised a vector layer (.gpkg format) with the function Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterise (vector to raster).
I have defined both the field to use (categorical), the raster extent and the resolution of the output pixel.
gdal_rasterize -l T_POLIGONOS -a CODIIGE -tr 3000.0 3000.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 -ot Float32 -of GPKG "C:/..../input.gpkg" "C:/..../output.gpkg"
The doubt arises when comparing the raster data with the vector data.
There are times when the raster chooses the predominant attribute in the raster area, but at other times it doesn't seem to match. What is the method for attribute selection when rasterising a vector format? Would it be possible to rasterize in QGIS taking the predominant atribute?

Some small test dataset that could be used for re-producing the issue would help.
